# Why am I getting a CustomOriginConfig instead of S3OriginConfig?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront

Following [this article](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/apn/using-amazon-cloudfront-with-multi-region-amazon-s3-origins/), I'm trying to serve my website's static content from multiple regions.

The lambda function in that article is trying to modify the property of an object within this path:

```
event.Records[0].cf.request.origin.s3
```

This is in the case that my lambda function is not receiving such a property. Instead, I'm getting:

```
event.Records[0].cf.request.origin.custom
```

Apparently, this means that I'm receiving a `CustomOriginConfig` while the article is expecting an `S3OriginConfig`. I'm not sure what these two mean but the UI depicted in the article for the "Edit Origin" page is totally different from mine.

The article shows this:

[image]

And I've got this:

[image]

Can someone please help me find why I'm receiving a `CustomOriginConfig` instead of an `S3OriginConfig`?

Comment: Is your origin domain name in the form of `${bucket}.s3-website.${region}.amazonaws.com`?  Or is it `${bucket}.s3.amazonaws.com`?

Comment: It's the first one: `${bucket}.s3-website.${region}.amazonaws.com`. Question: If I'm to use the second one, does that mean that I don't need to enable the `Static web hosting` on the bucket? I didn't know that I could name the S3 bucket directly!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

CloudFront only considers the origin to be an **S3 Origin** if the Origin Domain Name is the REST endpoint for the bucket -- e.g. `${bucketname}.s3.amazonaws.com`.  This is the configuration that supports authentication of requests on the back-side of CloudFront using an Origin Access Identity.

If you are using S3's web site hosting features (index and error documents, and/or redirects) then you use the web site hosting endpoint for the bucket, e.g. `${bucketname}.s3-website.${region}.amazonaws.com`.  CloudFront actually treats this configuration as a **Custom Origin**, the same as if you are using any (non-S3) web service as the origin server.  Origin Access Identity and S3 website endpoints are not compatible with each other.

The console options change depending on whether the console sees that you're creating an S3 or Custom Origin (based on the hostname).

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/DownloadDistS3AndCustomOrigins.html

Comment: Thanks. And good catch since I didn't share Origin Domain Name :)